# MacOSX installer created using Install4J different from standard app bundle

Tags: java, macos, bundle, install4j, launcher

While evaluating `Install4j` for `MacOSX` installers, the app generated is different in structure than a standard `MacOSX` app. The Executable type chosen is GUI in the Launcher configuration screen.

What we get currently is:

```
  xxx.jar                <==== jar file (provided to Install4j)
  .install4j
     \jre.bundle         <=== bundled jre (bundled by Install4j)
     <other install4j stuff>
  [Appname].app
      \MacOSX
         Launcher        <==== (generated by Install4j)   
      \Contents 
         \Resources 
           \resources
           <icon files>  <==== icons (provided to Install4j)
```

How do we place the respective files inside the `[Appname].app` folder created:

```
  [Appname].app
      \MacOSX
         Launcher        <==== (generated by Install4j)   
      \Contents 
         \Resources 
           \resources
           <icon files>  <==== icons (provided to Install4j)
           \jre          <=== bundled jre (bundled by Install4j)
           xxx.jar       <==== jar file (provided to Install4j)
```

The above is most useful and portable in `.tgz` file format, the end-user can unpack the file and drag and drop the `[Appname].app` into the `Applications` folder on the Mac system.

Comment: I would like to specify where the `.install4j` folder inside the `.tgz` archive should find its place. Ideally, I would place it in the `[Appname].app\Contents\Resources` folder in the `.jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "Folder archive" media file type, use the "Single bundle archive" media file type.

Comment: You mean the `.tgz` artifact by  "Folder archive" media file type and the `.dmg` file artifact by the option "Single bundle archive" media file?

We would like to use the `.tgz` format only and NOT the `.dmg` format due to our needs. Maybe we could place the expanded `jre` bundle into the Files section under File set and achieve this - this will place the `jre` folder where we want it (https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/steps/files/definition/definition.html).

I understand `Install4j` wlll find this folder and redirect calls from the launcher to use this `jre`.

Comment: Both folder archive as well as single bundle archive have the option to generate .tgz instead of .dmg ("Installer options" step in the media wizard). The location of the bundled JRE cannot be changed.